# Java Media Framework on client side?

Tags: java, applet, jmf

If I’m writing an applet that shows a video sequence (eg. streaming from a camera, or the applet itself is running the on the camera), do my clients need to download the Java Media Framework libraries inorder to see the sequence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you consider to use [Java FX](http://javafx.com/)? This technology is dealing with this problem of downloading media libraries and so no. Of course. It is still in development. If to be first-adopter is option, it will be worth of considering this.

Answer (score 1):

They need to install Java Media Framework on their computers, or you'll need to bundle the  JMF together with your applet somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If the applet makes use of the JMF libraries they need to be downloaded to the client machine (where the applet executes). However, JMF gets very little development from Sun (read none) and is pretty much legacy now (*subjective*).

Depending on how modern the camera is and what codecs it can output it may also be worth considering the video support in either [javafx](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/) of flash.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing the JMF.jar with your applet is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JAR ( Java DLL ) and put all the jar files from the install directory, JMF is 32-bit only, so the x86\java\JMF2.1.1e\lib is where it's usually located.

If you customized the customizer.jar you want that one too.

You can download it from a server like an applet and embed the applet inside and then run it. It's worked for me for 14+ years in Adult Pay sites.